# Why does dpkg give a "Broken pipe" error while installing an update?

Tags: updates, permissions, dpkg

Below is the error message `dpkg` gives me while running updates:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin.dpkg-new' (while processing `./lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin'): Permission denied
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

File: ‘/lib/firmware/brcm’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 1310841     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-04-22 05:06:10.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2015-10-08 22:21:45.910890160 -0700
Change: 2015-10-09 18:04:40.694151822 -0700
 Birth: -
```

*

```
[sudo] password for brian:
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done Calculating upgrade... 
Done The following packages will be upgraded:
   linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 0 B/24.7 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 6,144 B disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 230067 files and directories currently installed.)            
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.143.4_all.deb ... 
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.143.4) over (1.143.3) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.4_all.deb (--unpack):
  unable to create `/lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin.dpkg-new' (while processing `./lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin'): 
   Permission denied 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.4_all.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

*linux-firmware:
  Installed: 1.143.3
  Candidate: 1.143.4
  Version table:
     1.143.4 0
        500 http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu/ vivid-proposed/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.143.3 0
        500 http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.143 0
        500 http://mirror.os6.org/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Post the command

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `stat /lib/firmware/brcm`

Comment: Something doesn't match. Start the upgrade again.

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy linux-firmware`

Comment: Any reason using proposed packages?

Comment: I just assumed they are part of an update, I am not sure what those individual packages do...? Should I just delete them?

Comment: Start `apt-cache policy '.*' | grep -B 10 -A 10 'vivid-proposed'` and add the output here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the main server

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/mirror.os6.org/archive.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Remove the `vivid-proposed` repositories:

   ```
   sudo sed -i '/vivid-proposed/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

Comment: Seems to have worked.