# Unable to install updates apt-get install -f

Tags: updates, dependencies

I am unable to install updates over my ubuntu 14.04 machine, due to unmet dependencies for katepart, machine is suggesting me to use *apt-get install -f* to fix it after which it  is showing the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
kate-data
The following NEW packages will be installed:
kate-data
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
78 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,546 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 587315 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kate-data_4%3a4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking kate-data (4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kate-data_4%3a4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/nesc.xml',which is also in package nescc 1.3.4-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kate-data_4%3a4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it? I have tried the solution for problem [Why does dpkg give a “Broken pipe” error while installing an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686098/why-does-dpkg-give-a-broken-pipe-error-while-installing-an-update)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does dpkg give a "Broken pipe" error while installing an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/686098/why-does-dpkg-give-a-broken-pipe-error-while-installing-an-update)

Comment: Used the solution for that problem, still the problem remains

Comment: please [edit] your post with I have tried...

Answer (score 0):

The command should be 
`sudo apt-get install -f`

Try this:

1. `sudo apt-get autoclean`  (This clears the cache)
2. `sudo apt-get clean` (Almost the same as above,  but doesn't hurt to run anyway)
3. `sudo apt-get autoremove` (Just in case there's something ib the way

Then try to reinstall katepart.

Comment: tried the solution,still the following error persists- The following packages have unmet dependencies:
katepart : Depends: kate-data (>= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1) but it is not  installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the aptitude command. It seems it solves very well dependencies between packages and libraries. But first run the clean steps with aptitude and apt-get. Eventually update the repository with more download sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.